# Migrating from Go to Community with multiple stores

Tags: migration

I am migrating a store from Magento Go to Community. I've exported the customer and product databases.  My fields/ attributes are not the same as they were not managed by the same team. We are moving a UK-based site to be hosted on our US-based multisite installation.

I am asking for a best-practice other than column by column review of the csv.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the Import/Export tools have the option to map columns. There is no other way to magically have things "line up" from one system to the next. You will also need to rebuild composite product relationships, add missing attributes, and ensure that enumerated atrribute options are identical.